# Spring loads component before the needed bean

Tags: java, spring

I have an annotation based configuration class in my Spring project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean(name = "LDAP_TEMPLATE_BEAN")
    public LdapTemplate configLdapTemplate() {
        System.out.println("BEAN LDAP LOADED");
        LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
        lcs.setUrl("ldap://127.0.0.1:33389/");
//      lcs.setUserDn(BASE_DN);
        lcs.setDirObjectFactory(DefaultDirObjectFactory.class);
//      lcs.setAnonymousReadOnly(true);
        lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
        return new LdapTemplate(lcs);
    }
```

And a component class which needs the defined bean:

```
@Component
public class UserRepo {

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate; 

    public UserRepo() {
        System.out.println("UserRepo created");
```

When I start the project as Spring Boot App, the text of the UserRepo Constructor is shown before the text of the bean on the console output. And indeed, the variable ldapTemplate is null and causes of course exceptions.

How can I let the bean instantiation happen before the component instantiation, so the autowiring of ldapTemplate works?

Comment: Are you trying to use the `ldapTemplate` inside the constructor?

Comment: It's unclear to me how `@DependsOn` will help here. Where are you seeing the `ldapTemplate` as `null`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [@DependsOn](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) annotation to control beans initialization order.

Comment: Can you explain how using `@DependsOn` will fix _the variable ldapTemplate is `null`_?

Comment: The question was : "How can I let the bean instantiation happen before the component instantiation, so the autowiring of ldapTemplate works?".  It can be done with @DependsOn.

Comment: Let me repeat the question with _so the autowiring of `ldapTemplate` works_. How do you explain that _autowiring `ldapTemplate`_ wasn't working and that using `@DependsOn`  will make it work?

Comment: I used the ldapTemplate in another function I haven't shown in the code above. The usage of this function has always thrown a nullpointer-exception because ldaptemplate was null. It was clear, because the config-bean was loaded after the instantiation of the class where ldaptemplate is located. So a "@DependsOn("LDAP_TEMPLATE_BEAN")" above the UserRepo class fixed the problem.

Comment: @Paul No that is not possible on its own. Spring will not leave an `@Autowired` field `null` if annotation configuration is enabled. It will throw an exception stating that it can't autowire the field. `@DependsOn` will not fix that. Please respond with `@username`, otherwise I won't get notified.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, this is true, but Spring finds the bean after the autowired field. It seems that spring does not return back to the autowired field when it has found the bean, so the field keeps empty and causes a null pointer exception at usage. I guess spring doesn't throw a bean not found exception because it finds bean but at the wrong time

Comment: @Paul No. Please provide a reproducible example of what you are describing. Just the fact that a bean A has an `@Autowired` field of type B, means that A has a dependency on B and B has to be created before A. `@DependsOn` adds **nothing**.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that a bean can be injected into another bean object before that object is initialized. Spring needs to first instantiate your bean class (invoke its constructor) before it can inject any fields.

One option is to use constructor injection

```
@Autowired
public UserRepo(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
```

or move the code in the constructor to a `@PostConstruct` annotated method

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // will get invoked after all injections
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work. I posted question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601746/spring-boot-repository-scanning-fails-but-creating-bean-manully-in-config-works#38601788