# spring error No qualifying bean of type JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

I have a spring boot application where I am creating `Datasource` and `JdbcTemplate` manually in my config because I need to decrypt datasource password.

I am using tomcat `DataSource` (`org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`)  as recommended in spring boot docs since I am configuring connection properties.

I am excluding autoconfiguration for datasource (see `Application.java`) since I am creating one manually.

**Application.java**

```
// exclude datasourceAutoConfiguration since we are creating manaully creating datasource bean in AppConfig
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my `application.properties` file

```
jdbc.hostdb.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hello-world:1122/foobar
host.jdbc.hostdb.username=foo
host.jdbc.hostdb.password=encryptedPassword
host.jdbc.hostdb.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
secret=afasdfansdfsdfsd
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

@ComponentScan("com.company.foo")
public class AppConfig {


    @Value("${jdbc.hostdb.driver}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${jdbc.hostdb.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${jdbc.hostdb.username}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${jdbc.hostdb.password}")
    private String pass;

    @Value("${secret}")
    private String secret;


    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource_mydb(Encryption encryption) {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(hostdb_driver);
        ds.setUrl(hostdb_url);
        ds.setUsername(hostdb_user);
        ds.setPassword(encryption.decrypt(hostdb_pass));
        return ds;
    }


    @Bean
    Encryption encryption() {
        return new Encryption(secret);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

**MyRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MyRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

when I start spring container, I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyRepository' defined in file [/Users//Documents/codebase/my-service/build/classes/main/com/company/foo/MyRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.concur.cognos.authentication.Application.main(Application.java:14) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

2016-07-26 1
```

Comment: There's no bean defined for `AppConfig`. Maybe you meant to annotate it with `@Configuration`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: yes, that fixed it. I dont know how I missed it. Thanks for catching it

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: i do need `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` in order to avoid autoconfiguration or does spring sees my datasource bean and not autoconfigure it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: you may have an answer to this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511755/how-can-i-have-a-datasource-object-that-is-not-a-bean-in-spring

Comment: You don't need to exclude the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` as that is smart enough to see that you already added the `DataSource`. You also don't need to create a `JdbcTemplate` as that will be automatically created for you. So you only would need to create the `DataSource`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the arguments of your bean definitions. Where would their values come from? For example -

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Here you haven't specified where would value of `dataSource` argument come from. Same case of `datasource_mydb` bean. Use `@Autowire` on bean definitions acception other beans as input arguments.

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public DataSource datasource_mydb(Encryption encryption) {
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(hostdb_driver);
    ds.setUrl(hostdb_url);
    ds.setUsername(hostdb_user);
    ds.setPassword(encryption.decrypt(hostdb_pass));
    return ds;
}


@Bean
Encryption encryption() {
    return new Encryption(secret);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
@Qualifier("datasource_mydb")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: I dont think it is necessary. @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you think?

Comment: No, this isn't necessary at all. @brainstorm Spring will resolve arguments for `@Bean` methods by checking the context for corresponding beans. You've defined a `DataSource` bean named `datasource_mydb` and so it's available for the `JdbcTemplate` bean method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and doc link for validating this? If this is the case then the reason for OP's error is bean's name "datasource_mydb" which does not map by name "dataSource".

Comment: [Here's the official doc on this process](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-dependencies). Injection doesn't happen by name here. It happens by type.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible...
You might not have added JdbcTemplate dependency in project configuration file(.xml file).

Answer (score -1):

Please use spring dependency for DataSource and JdbcTemplate. After that you can autowired DataSource and JdbcTemplate. hopefully it will work.